# Running Scipy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, numpy, scipy, blas

I got Numpy and Matplotlib running on Heroku, and I'm trying to install Scipy as well. However, Scipy requires BLAS[1] to install, which is not presented on the Heroku platform. After contacting Heroku support, they suggested me to build BLAS as a static library to deploy, and setup the necessary environment variables.

So, I compiled libblas.a on a 64bit Linux box, and set the following variables as described in [2] :

```
$ heroku config
BLAS             => .heroku/vendor/lib/libfblas.a
LD_LIBRARY_PATH  => .heroku/vendor/lib
LIBRARY_PATH     => .heroku/vendor/lib
PATH             => bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PYTHONUNBUFFERED => true
```

After adding scipy==0.10.1 in my requirements.txt, the push still fails.

```
     File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration

       blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)

     File "/tmp/build_h5l5y31i49e8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 311, in get_info

       return cl().get_info(notfound_action)

     File "/tmp/build_h5l5y31i49e8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 462, in get_info

       raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)

   numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:

       Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

       Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

       numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

       the BLAS environment variable.
```

It seem that pip is not aware of the BLAS environment variable, so I check the environment using heroku run python:

```
(venv)bash-3.2$ heroku run python
Running python attached to terminal... import up, run.1
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 31 2011, 16:22:04) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('bash')
~ $ echo $BLAS
.heroku/vendor/lib/libfblas.a
~ $ ls .heroku/vendor/lib/libfblas.a
.heroku/vendor/lib/libfblas.a
~ $
```

And it seems fine. Now I have no idea how to solve this.

[1] http://www.netlib.org/blas/
[2] http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux

Answer (score 15):

I managed to get this working on the cedar stack by building numpy and scipy offline as bdists and then modifying the heroku python buildpack to unzip these onto the dyno's vendor/venv areas directly.  You can also use the buildpack to set environment variables that persist.

Heroku haven't officially published buildpacks yet - search for 'heroku buildpacks' for more thirdparty/heroku ones and information.

My fork of the python build pack is here:
https://wyn@github.com/wyn/heroku-buildpack-python.git

The changes are in the bin/compile where I source two new steps, a scipy/numpy step and an openopt step.  The scripts for the two steps are in bin/steps/npscipy and bin/steps/openopt.  I also added some variables to bin/release.  Note that I am assuming installation through a setup.py file rather than the requirements.txt approach (c.f. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#traditional_distributions).

I also download the blas/lapack/atlas/gfortran binaries that were used to build numpy/scipy onto the dyno as there are c extensions that need to link through to them.  The reason for building everything offline and downloading is that pip-installing numpy/scipy requires you to have a fortran compiler + associated dev environment and this made my slugs too big.

It seems to work, the slug size is now 35mb and scaling seems fast too.  All but one of the numpy tests pass and all of the scipy tests pass.

This is still work in progress for me but I thought I'd share.

Comment: sorry forgot to say, if you want to use the buildpack as is then do: $ heroku create appname --stack=cedar --buildpack=git@github.com:wyn/heroku-buildpack-python.git

Comment: Thanks, I'm enjoying playing with the cedar stack and build packs.  I'm now looking into the vulcan builder, I think it would be good to get these things built with that...

Comment: Hello - no afraid not, I just built them on my Ubuntu Oineric (?) 64 bit as bdist packages i.e. set BLAS and LAPACK env vars and then do python setup.py bdist

Comment: Amazing work. Thanks! I'm having a problem, however, when importing the scipy.stats module. I get the following exception: ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @paul hello, sorry am at work at the moment so cannot look into this right now but often that means that the client module cannot link the .so file?  Have you tried logging onto your dyno through the bash client and using ldd to see what liblapack.so.3gf thinks is missing?

Comment: I think the problem is that liblapack.so.3gf is missing completely?

Comment: Hello @paul: I have just been looking at this and I think it is to do with my using the git@ url syntax rather than git:// urls - I suspect that the buildpack didn't even install correctly for you?  I have remedied this in my buildpack and recommend using: $ heroku create --stack=cedar --buildpack=git://github.com/wyn/heroku-buildpack-python.git

Comment: I have also put a small toy example on github (git://github.com/wyn/npsp-helloworld.git) that goes into a bit more detail and allows you to try an example that I know works for me.  @aaronsw: sorry for the late reply, I don't have a public example to show hopefully the toy example will suffice?  I hope to spend some time over xmas working on a blog post that goes into more detail on the asynchronous approach.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone else comes to this like I did...

The [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819968/running-scipy-on-heroku/10632272#10632272) on this question from [@coshx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400423/coshx) sadly no longer works (at least I could not get it to work).  What I did, however was the following:

1. I forked [npsicpy-binaries](https://github.com/wyn/npscipy-binaries) repository from @coshx and changed all the tar files such that they do not have `venv` as the root folder inside (my fork is [here](https://github.com/kmp1/npscipy-binaries))
2. I forked the [npsp-helloworld](https://github.com/wyn/npsp-helloworld) repository from @coshx and made it use a `requirements.txt` file instead of the setup.py (my fork is [here](https://github.com/kmp1/npsp-helloworld) - this means that you can use the whole pip approach).
3. I forked the [heroku-buildpack-python](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) repository from Heroku, took the [npscipy](https://github.com/wyn/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/npscipy) file from @coshx and changed it to work with this latest version of the build pack (my fork is [here](https://github.com/kmp1/heroku-buildpack-python) - you can see that there is no venv set up, for example).

After doing those three things I have the [npsp-helloworld](https://github.com/wyn/npsp-helloworld) application working perfectly.  You just need to make sure you set the buildpack appropriately when creating the application and you are good to go:

```
$ heroku create --stack=cedar --buildpack=https://github.com/kmp1/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

NOTE:  I haven't worked out how to make my own binaries yet, so the three libraries (scipy, numpy and scikit-learn) are not the latest versions  so make sure when you install it you do (if anyone can build these I would gladly accept a pull request for them):

```
pip install scipy==0.11.0
pip install numpy==1.7.0
pip install scikit-learn==0.13.1
```

*By the way - I am really sorry if I have not done things in the correct way, etiquette-wise.  I'm still learning git and this whole open source thing.*

Answer (score 8):

Another good option is the [conda buildpack](https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack), which allows you to add any of the free Linux64 packages available through Anaconda/Miniconda to a Heroku app. Some of the most popular packages include numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels, pandas, and cvxopt. While the buildpack makes it fairly simple to add packages to an app, the downsides are that the buildback takes up a lot of space and that you have to wait on Anaconda to update the libraries in the repository.

If you are starting a new Python app on Heroku, you can add the conda buildpack using the command:

```
$ heroku create YOUR_APP_NAME --buildpack https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack.git
```

If you have already setup a Python app on Heroku, you can add the conda buildpack to the existing app using the command:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack.git
```

Or, if you need to specify the app by name:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack.git --app YOUR_APP_NAME
```

To use the buildpack, you will need to include two text files in the app directory, requirements.txt and conda-requirements.txt. Just as with the standard Python buildpack, the requirements.txt file lists packages that should be installed using pip. Packages that should be installed using conda are listed in the conda-requirements.txt file. Some of the most useful scientific packages include numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels, pandas, and cvxopt. The full list of available conda packages can be found at [repo.continuum.io](https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/index.html).

For example:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
gunicorn==0.14.2
requests==0.11.1

$ cat conda-requirements.txt
scipy
numpy
cvxopt
```

That’s it! You can now add Anaconda packages to a Python app on Heroku.

Comment: [A clear explanation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps) for why the conda buildpack exists.  Note that this buildpack is maintained by Kenneth Reitz, who is ["responsible for the technical design of Heroku's Python offering."](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kennethreitz)

Comment: I tried this buildpack but cannot proceed because it only supports Django 1.x packages. Is there an option for Django 2?

Answer (score 3):

The slug compiler is not aware of your environment variables, which is why it fails during push, and not once running.

The only real option you have is to look at the `user_env_compile` addon that's currently in labs beta.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Answer (score 1):

For those who wish to use Python 3.4 in production, I've built numpy 1.8.1, scipy 0.14.0, and scikit-learn 0.15-git (0.14 doesn't work with the others for some reason) as binaries on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit, which works on the Heroku cedar stack. [Here is the git repo](https://github.com/transcranial/npscipy-binaries).

My heroku buildpack is quite similar to that of [kmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039947/kmp). Note that the bin/steps/npscipy file links to my repository of binaries above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this here in case someone stumbled on this like I do. Since I am using python 3.4, [thenovices buildpack](https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy/tree/python3) doesn't work out for me.

I tried to look at conda buildpack, but it seems like a little bit of an overkill for my application which only requires scipy and numpy. What finally works for me is [this excellent guide](http://hackersome.com/p/icoxfog417/heroku-buildpack-python), using a multi buildpacks approach. The scipy installation was indeed a bit long though. Hope this helps! :)