# Web application that uses scikit-learn

Tags: python, web-applications, scikit-learn

I have locally trained a [sklearn](http://scikits.appspot.com/scikit-learn) classifier and I have to create a simple web application that demonstrate its use. I'm a complete noob on web app development and I don't want to waste hours on creating a web app using a framework that doesn't support the modules I'm using.

1. What do you suggest would be a good approach for this task?
2. What web app development framework should I use (if any)?
3. Do I have to dive into things like `Heroku` , `django` etc. or is there more simple and quicker solutions for a simple scientific demo?

My thought was to take the classifier I trained, pickle it and un-pickle it on the server, then to run `classify` from the server, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: @zthomas.nc What do you mean by better solution? From your blog post it's the most simple and standard way to do so. If you are looking for a better deployment solution, you can use docker. If it's about representation that splitting UI and backend part into Flask/ReactJs app could be a fit. I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @GensaGames Fair, maybe I need to just write up the crux of that blog post and have it be an answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If this is just for a demo, train your classifier offline, pickle the model and then use a simple python web framework such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) to unpickle the model at server startup time and call the predict function in an HTTP request handler.

django is a feature complete framework hence is longer to learn than flask or bottle but it has a great documentation and a larger community.

heroku is a service to host your application in the cloud. It's possible to [host flask applications on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python/), here is a [simple template project + instructions](https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku) to do so.

For "production" setups I would advise you not to use pickle but to write your own persistence layer for the machine learning model so as to have full control on the parameters your store and be more robust to library upgrades that might break the unpickling of old models.

Comment: After fiddling with flask and heroku I have a problem working with sklearn, because it requires scipy which requiers blas which I don't have a clue on how to install it on heroku... any thoughts?

Comment: Indeed I did not think about that. Apparently other people managed to get it working this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819968/running-scipy-on-heroku

Comment: for production setup, check [Model persistence using joblib.dump](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

Comment: just to complete the picture, at the end I uploaded the weights to a no sql database and implemented the classify function on the server. It worked fast and was pretty easy to update.

Answer (score 3):

While this is not a classifier, I have implemented a simple machine learning web service using  the bottle framework and scikit-learn. Given a dataset in .csv format it returns 2D visualizations with respect to principal components analysis and linear discriminant analysis techniques.

More information and example data files can be found at: http://mindwriting.org/blog/?p=153

Here is the implementation:
upload.html:

```
<form
 action="/plot" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" value="PCA & LDA" />
</form>
```

pca_lda_viz.py (modify host name and port number):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from cStringIO import StringIO

from bottle import route, run, request, static_file
import csv
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import colorsys

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.lda import LDA

html = '''
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{}" />
    </body>
</html>
'''

 @route('/')
 def root():
     return static_file('upload.html', root='.')

 @route('/plot', method='POST')
    def plot():

       # Get the data
       upload = request.files.get('upload')
       mydata = list(csv.reader(upload.file, delimiter=','))

       x = [row[0:-1] for row in mydata[1:len(mydata)]]

       classes =  [row[len(row)-1] for row in mydata[1:len(mydata)]]
       labels = list(set(classes))
       labels.sort()

       classIndices = np.array([labels.index(myclass) for myclass in classes])

       X = np.array(x).astype('float')
       y = classIndices
       target_names = labels

       #Apply dimensionality reduction
       pca = PCA(n_components=2)
       X_r = pca.fit(X).transform(X)

       lda = LDA(n_components=2)
       X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)

        #Create 2D visualizations
       fig = plt.figure()
       ax=fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
       bx=fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

       fontP = FontProperties()
       fontP.set_size('small')

       colors = np.random.rand(len(labels),3)

       for  c,i, target_name in zip(colors,range(len(labels)), target_names):
           ax.scatter(X_r[y == i, 0], X_r[y == i, 1], c=c, 
                      label=target_name,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
           ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, -0.05),
                     fancybox=True,shadow=True, ncol=len(labels),prop=fontP)
           ax.set_title('PCA')
           ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)

       for c,i, target_name in zip(colors,range(len(labels)), target_names):
           bx.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], c=c, 
                      label=target_name,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
           bx.set_title('LDA');
           bx.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)

       # Encode image to png in base64
       io = StringIO()
       fig.savefig(io, format='png')
       data = io.getvalue().encode('base64')

       return html.format(data)

run(host='mindwriting.org', port=8079, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the tutorial below to deploy your scikit-learn model in Azure ML and get the web service automatically generated:

[Build and Deploy a Predictive Web App Using Python and Azure ML](http://blogs.technet.com/b/machinelearning/archive/2015/08/21/build-and-deploy-a-predictive-web-app-using-python-and-azure-ml.aspx)

or the combination of [yHat](https://www.yhathq.com/) + [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) may also do the trick

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a Docker image that wraps `predict` and `predictproba` methods and expose them as a web api: https://github.com/hexacta/docker-sklearn-predict-http-api

You need to save your model:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'iris-svc.pkl')
```

create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM hexacta/sklearn-predict-http-api:latest
COPY iris-svc.pkl /usr/src/app/model.pkl
```

and run the container:

```
$ docker build -t iris-svc .
$ docker run -d -p 4000:8080 iris-svc
```

then you can make requests:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"sepal length (cm)":4.4}' http://localhost:4000/predictproba
  [{"0":0.8284069169,"1":0.1077571623,"2":0.0638359208}]
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '[{"sepal length (cm)":4.4}, {"sepal length (cm)":15}]' http://localhost:4000/predict
  [0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Plotly Dash for a demo or even for an app with limited scope.

https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/Portal/ for some examples with code source. You have machine learning examples with sklearn.

https://dash.plotly.com/deployment for deployment, mainly with Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

If you go the flask route, I highly recommend that you watch the Corey Shafer series on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/MwZwr5Tvyxo).  It's a solid series that will get you underway quickly, and there are many helpful notes from other viewers in the comment section.

Additionally, since I presume you'll build your models elsewhere and look to score them on your site, you will likely want to use pickle to store the model objects after development, and then load the model objects using pickle within your flask `config.py`.