# How to import scikit-learn in python virtual environment?

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, scikit-learn, python-venv

### The Problem

I'm trying to use scikit-learn on a virtual environment and I cannot get it to run.

So, for example, I go to a project folder and install NumPy, SciPy, and scikit-learn

`virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn`

Then I open python and try to import each of them.

`import numpy
import scipy
import sklearn`

NumPy and SciPy import fine, but when I try to import I get an error saying `Library not loaded: @rpath/./libgfortran.3.dylib`.

Is there something I'm missing in the installation?

Full error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 324, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/./libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Peter/git/dataSandbox/flaskApps/sfSalary/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.so
  Reason: image not found`

EDIT:
this was some troubleshooting to host a Heroku app using sklearn.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend **against** using virtual environments for NumPy/SciPy/Scikit-learn and other packages which include compiled code. Virtual environments deal with pure Python dependencies reasonably well, but for compiled extensions with dependencies outside Python, they can fail in unexpected ways (as you have seen).

If you want to manage multiple environments with different versions of Python packages including compiled extensions, the best tool out there is probably [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/), and in particular [conda environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).

With it, you can run the following:

```
$ conda create -n myenv python=3.4 numpy scipy scikit-learn
$ source activate myenv
(myenv) $ python
Python 3.4.3
>>> import sklearn
```

and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp! Upvote pending... Yep, switching to a conda environment was key. For anyone who may be interested, this was for the sake of using sklearn in a Heroku app. Turns out another requirement was updating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635857/how-to-install-scikit-learn-on-heroku-cedar) and you should be good to go

Comment: Nice answer but what if I want to stay in virtualenvironment and do not switch to conda?

Comment: Then it's up to you to manually manage your virtual environment's interaction with non-python system dependencies.