# Deploying Pandas to Heroku?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, heroku

I've successfully installed numpy, scipy, and sic-kit learn on Heroku. I thought I successfully added pandas, but when I run my app it crashes with the following error:

```
ImportError: C extension: liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Not sure how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635857/how-to-install-scikit-learn-on-heroku-cedar?

Answer (score 2):

There are several buildpacks that allows you to install scikit learn (note that liblapack is a requirement of scipy). Just add one to your buildpacks as follows:

`$heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy`

Note: you will need to install precise versions of the libraries to make it work. In my case I use (copy paste them in your requirements.txt)

`numpy==1.9.1
scikit-learn==0.16.1
scipy==0.14.0`

Comment: Hi Luke! Thanks for this. In fact I originally was using this build pack with the said versions, but was getting a different error (can't remember what it was maybe a blas related one). So I switched to `https://github.com/andrewychoi/heroku-buildpack-scipy`. You mention that `liblapack` is a spicy requirement. So would this mean it's not a problem with pandas?

Comment: @KingPolygon Liblapack is a linear algebra library extremely fast written in fortran that is required by scipy. Scipy is in turn a dependency of pandas, so there is no getting out of this, unluckily. You can try using my custom buildpacks for scientific calculus (rpy2, pandas, scipy, sklearn..) `1. https://github.com/luke14free/heroku-buildpack-r
2. https://github.com/luke14free/heroku-buildpack-scipy`

Comment: @KingPolygon don't forget to accept this answer if I solved your issue :)