# Install Matploblib via pip in a virtualenv to push to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

How can I install numpy,scipy,matplotlib on Heroku?

So first locally I'm doing pip install matplotlib -> i get an error saying install numpy..
so i do pip install numpy and get an error saying

```
  File "/home/sghose/myapp/helloflask/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 410, in generate_config_h

    moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 41, in check_types

    out = check_types(*a, **kw)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 271, in check_types

    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/sghose/myapp/helloflask/build/numpy
```

...what do I do now? Typically I would just do apt-get install python-numpy ... but then I'm thinking pip won't pick it up and then Heroku will be unhappy when I push... also I see a previous post where they recompiled numpy,scipy, matplotlib and changed vars so that they pointed to heroku packages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819968/running-scipy-on-heroku) ? Is this still necessary? Sounds somewhat painful >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How Heroku installs dependencies

When you push code to Heroku, Heroku will *only* look at your `requirements.txt` file and install the packages that are listed in there.

### How you list those dependencies

Heroku doesn't care about how you created that file (by hand, or using `pip freeze`), so nothing prevents you from adding a package to the `requirements.txt` file, you just have to add a line in there with the name of the requirement.

### How that solves your issue

Once you add the `matplotlib` line to your `requirements.txt` file, you can then push your code to Heroku, and they [will figure out what to do](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#can-i-require-modules-with-c-extensions) with your `matplotlib` requirement.

If that doesn't work, you can always contact Heroku, but if the only requirement is the python headers, I'd be surprised if it wasn't available on Heroku.

---

Regarding local installation, Ben Mezger's answer is right, you just have to:

- `apt-get install` the python headers (these are *not* a python package, so you don't install them with pip). Heroku likely has those available already.
- Install the package using pip, it will then compile properly.

Comment: um... I don't understand sorry. How do I know the matplotlib version number? .. but that is more trivial. my real problem is how will it get heroku to download matplotlib.. i doubt it will apt-get it?

Comment: *is this assuming that they have the python headers so pip will work?

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf Yes. I think they do have those headers. They will use `pip` to install what's in your `requirements.txt` file. The whole point of using Heroku is not having to care. Just drop the requirement in your file and you're set. By the way, the version number is optional in a `requirements.txt` file

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I updated my answer to make it a bit clearer, let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python-dev

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

or

```
apt-get install python-devel
```

Comment: .... but via pip? pastie.org/5135107 -> cannot find.

From my understanding if i used apt-get pip won't pick it up, and then i can't do pip freeze and then I won't be able to push the requirements file to heroku so that it knows what to do...

Comment: No, in your Linux package manager. I posted it above; sudo apt-get install python-dev

Comment: Yes I did that. but afterwards...?  is this having the implicit assumption that they should have python-dev already installed?

Comment: Heroku doesn't seem to have "python-dev" Ubuntu package installed by default.