# How to deploy matplotlib on heroku - fulfilling numpy requirement

Tags: heroku, matplotlib

I'm trying to deploy a web app on Heroku that uses matplotlib. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131512/install-matploblib-via-pip-in-a-virtualenv-to-push-to-heroku) is related but doesn't seem to address my specific problem. More precisely, I'm deploying a duplicate app "staging" for testing purposes. When I run the command:

```
git push staging master
```

to push my app to Heroku I get an unexpected Heroku push rejection:

```
           ============================================================================
           BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                       matplotlib: 1.1.1
                           python: 2.7.2 (default, Oct 31 2011, 16:22:04)  [GCC 4.4.3]
                         platform: linux2

           REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                            numpy: no
                                   * You must install numpy 1.4 or later to build
                                   * matplotlib.
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']

       ============================================================================

       BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

                   matplotlib: 1.1.1

                       python: 2.7.2 (default, Oct 31 2011, 16:22:04)  [GCC 4.4.3]

                     platform: linux2



       REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

                        numpy: no

                               * You must install numpy 1.4 or later to build

                               * matplotlib.

       ----------------------------------------
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/build_sj82km4g47z3/.heroku/venv/build/matplotlib
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:warm-atoll-3630.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:warm-atoll-3630.git'
```

Unexpected because I thought I had resolved this problem. Indeed my production app is working just fine. I resolved it by having a two layered requirements file.

requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.6.2
-r ./prod-requirements.txt
```

prod-requirements.txt:

```
matplotlib==1.1.1
other requirements...
```

Clearly I have forgotten how I actually resolved this issue. I remember that because of the way matplotlib depends on numpy and how Heroku installs requirements via pip that this is tricky.  Here is the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797688/matplotlib-requirements-with-pip-install-in-virtualenv) I'm referring to. What can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing matplotlib from my prod-requirements.txt file (see orginal question). Then deploying, then adding matplotlib to my prod-requirements.txt file then deploying again. I had assumed that's what was achieving by having  a requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.6.2
-r ./prod-requirements.txt
```

And then putting matplotlib=1.1.1 in the prod-requirements file .
But apparently not. It seems likely that i could have achieved this with just one requirements file.