# Building NumPy for Heroku Using Vulcan

Tags: python, heroku, numpy

Has anyone successfully built NumPy for Heroku using the vulcan build tool?

When trying to do so I get the following error:

```
Packaging local directory... done
Uploading source package... done
Building with: ./configure --prefix /app/vendor/numpy-1.6 && make install
sh: ./configure: not found
bin/vulcan-make:69:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /app/vendor/numpy-1.6 (Errno::ENOENT)
from bin/vulcan-make:69:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from bin/vulcan-make:18:in `chdir'
from bin/vulcan-make:18:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
from bin/vulcan-make:17:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 'numpy' to requirements.txt, like any other dependency.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. I realized after the fact that my issue was really with scipy, not numpy. Here's my fork of the scipy/scikit-learn buildpack, updated to work with the most recent official buildpack: https://github.com/OysterBooks/heroku-buildpack-python

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the command you're invoking and from what directory (in relation to where the make script is).

Note that NumPy is already [an installable dependency on Heroku](https://twitter.com/poweredbyaltnet/status/206153713633607680). More resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819968/running-scipy-on-heroku) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635857/how-to-install-scikit-learn-on-heroku-cedar) and [here](https://gist.github.com/3680810).

You might also want to take a look at [Anvil](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil), announcement [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/buildpack-developers/Z-ZZVSx61eY).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the command you want vulcan to build numpy with. This is done with the -c flag.

```
vulcan build -s ./numpy-1.6 -c "python setup.py install --prefix=/tmp/numpy-1.6" -p /tmp/numpy-1.6
```

At least this is similar to the command I ran to have it succeed.